# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have seen this question posted in several places. The issue seems to be with updating past gradle version 3 and android studio version 3. Whenever I change my dependencies to a newer version I keep getting the error:

```
Could not find method implementation() for arguments [androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
        implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0')

    }
}
```

my gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

I appreciate any help. Been trying to get my app running on Android for a day now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove these lines in the `buildscript` block of the top level file:

```
//implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
//implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02
```

You have to add these dependencies in the the `dependencies` block of the `module/build.gradle` file.

Also remove the `dependencies` block inside the `allprojects` block

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        //...
    }
    repositories {
        //..
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        //..
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```